# How to wrap custom <root> element around whole HTML document?

Tags: python, html, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a large number of HTML documents that must be converted to XML. Not all may look exactly the same. For example, the sample below ends with an HTML comment tag, not with the HTML tag.

Note this question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28588603).

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<comment>this is an HTML comment</comment>
<comment>this is another HTML comment</comment>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
        ...
        <comment>here is a comment inside the head tag</comment>
</head>
<body>
        ...
        <comment>Comment inside body tag</comment>
<comment>Another comment inside body tag</comment>
<comment>There could be many comments in each file and scattered, not just 1 in the head and three in the body. This is just a sample.</comment>
</body>
</html>
<comment>This comment is the last line of the file</comment>
```

I wish to wrap the entire document with a custom tag called `<root>`. So far, the best I can do is wrap `<root>` around `<html>`.

```
root_tag = bs4.Tag(name="root")
soup.html.wrap(root_tag)
```

How can I position the `<root>` element such that it wraps the entire document?

Comment: Is each HTML document its own file? Or is this scraped data in memory

Comment: Each HTML document is its own file

Answer (score 0):

A little crude, as this is just wrapping any given file in `<root> </root>`

See if it works for your use case:

```
def root_wrap(file):
    fin = open(file, 'r+')
    fin.write('<root>')
    for line in fin:
        fin.write(line)
    fin.write('</root>')
    fin.close()
```