# cant use case conversion by "regex" and "re" module in python

Tags: python, regex

```
import regex
st = """
<!-- Start of page -->
<HTML>
<!-- Start of head -->
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Title</TITLE> <!-- Page title -->
</HEAD>
<!-- Body -->
<BODY>
"""
pat = regex.compile(r"<!-{2,}(.*?)-{2,}>")
st2 = pat.sub(r'\U\1\E', st)
print(st2)
```

In the above code, I am trying to implement a Case Conversion operation using "regex" module(indeed used "re" module too) and what I want to do is To convert all text between comments written in HTML to upper Case, for example `<!-- Start of page -->` TO `<!-- START OF PAGE -->`, but When I try to do so, With this syntactically correct code, that should have worked It gives me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/m.m/PycharmProjects/untitled9/source.py", line 13, in <module>
st2 = pat.sub(r'\U\1\E', st)
File "C:\Users\m.m\.virtualenvs\untitled5\lib\site-packages\regex\regex.py", line 676, in 
_compile_replacement_helper
is_group, items = _compile_replacement(source, pattern, is_unicode)
File "C:\Users\m.m\.virtualenvs\untitled5\lib\site-packages\regex\_regex_core.py", line 1696, in 
_compile_replacement
return False, [parse_repl_hex_escape(source, HEX_ESCAPES[ch], ch)]
File "C:\Users\m.m\.virtualenvs\untitled5\lib\site-packages\regex\_regex_core.py", line 1764, in 
parse_repl_hex_escape
source.string, source.pos)
regex._regex_core.error: incomplete escape \U at position 3
```

It seem's that it does not know what is the purpose of `\U` and `\L` and gives "**incomplete escape error**"

I am currently using python 3.7 and I have tried to do so, with "re" module too, but it does not work.

I wanted to know , what is the problem ?, I have seen many books used to do case conversion with regex. but The fact that "Why should not this work ?" has been an enigma for me.

Is the problem from the syntax, or does it originate from the python implementation of regex itself, that does not support such operation to convert cases?

In This question, I am trying to convert the text using `\E` etc, or formally "using CaseConversion in regex"

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty, No, In that question,  "\U" and "\E" is not used to convert cases, And This how my question differs from that.

Comment: Are there no HTML parsers/libraries that allow you to modify comments? Using RegEx for this seems horrible.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Why is it horrible ?, I have seen that in the book "Sams teach yourself regular expression".!!, Its a bit enigmatic for me.

Comment: Also, you state _it does not know what is the purpose of `\U` and `\L`_ yet your code contains `\U` and `\E`. Which is it?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I Stated That because It was weird for me... to see that why does not python "regex" or "re" module does not know what is the purpose of that , while it should know !!?

Comment: @MohVahedi I’m asking whether your are using **\U and \L** or **\U and \E**. I’m not certain that the error is caused by the `re` module’s inability to handle certain valid expressions.

Comment: I’m having trouble finding information on `\E`, do you know of any good resources for either one?

Comment: @MohVahedi I would be interested in seeing that book. In any case, here is a similar question right here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28588603/11301900.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, [you can see `\E` and etc here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html)

Comment: @MohVahedi Ah, it looks like it is indeed unsupported in Python. Too bad!

Comment: @MohVahedi Unless i’m misinterpreting the table, it says “3.7 error” in the rightmost column.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Sorry I was wrong(I did not refresh the browser), Anyway... Thanks for your patience and caring.

Comment: @MohVahedi No problem! Did you take a look at the link about using BeautifulSoup for this? I will write up a full solution tomorrow.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, Yes I am working on that solution too, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(re.sub(r"<!-{2,}(.*?)-{2,}>",lambda x:"<!--"+x.group(1).upper()+"-->",st))
```

This is using the `re` module, `sub` can take the second argument as a string or as a callable, if it is a callable every match is sent as a argument to the callable, you can then do normal operations using that object.

This gives

```
<!--START OF PAGE-->
<HTML>
<!--START OF HEAD-->
<HEAD>
<TITLE>My Title</TITLE> <!--PAGE TITLE-->
</HEAD>
<!--BODY-->
<BODY>
```

Comment: would you state, why does not using "\U" and "\E" suffice ?

Comment: Why split and map the group result?

Comment: I am sorry, "Case conversion using what I Stated is not supported in python" and it gives error according to this resource which indeed is true [resource](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refreplacecase.html)

Comment: @TheNamesAlc Don’t forget to actually edit your answer once the realization has hit ;)